# Não consigo inserir email ao banco de dados PHP - mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

estou tentando inserir um simples email ao banco de dados chamado 
"newsletter_emails". A verificação se um determinado usuário já está no banco de dados funciona. O trecho começa em "News Letter"

```
<?php

require 'conexao.php';

// mensagem de erro
$nomeEr = $emailEr = $msgEr = $emailMsg = "";
// variáveis
$nome = $email = $msg = "";

// News letter
if(isset($_POST['letteremail']) && !empty($_POST['letteremail'])) {

    $letteremail = addslashes($_POST['letteremail']);



    //consulta na tabela
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM newsletter_emails WHERE email = '$letteremail'";
    $sql = $pdo->query($sql);

    // verifica se há emails
    if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
        $Lemail = $sql->fetch();

        // compara os emails
        if($Lemail['email'] == $letteremail) {
            $emailMsg = "Você já é um inscrito!";

        } else {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter_emails SET email = '$letteremail'";
            $sql = $pdo->query($sql);
        }


    }
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["nome"])) {
        $nomeEr = "*";
    } else {
        $nome = valida($_POST["nome"]);
        //verifica se o nome contém apenas letras e espaço
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $nome)) {
            $nomeEr = "Apenas letras e espaço";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailEr = "*";
    } else {
        $email = valida($_POST["email"]);
        // checa se o email está no formato correto
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailEr = "Formato de email inválido";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["msg"])) {
        $msgEr = "*";
    } else {
        $msg = valida($_POST["msg"]);
    }
}



function valida($dado) {
    $dado = trim($dado);
    $dado = stripcslashes($dado);
    $dado = htmlspecialchars($dado);

    return $dado;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 3):

Problema de sintaxe mesmo e está aqui:

```
"INSERT INTO newsletter_emails SET email = '$letteremail'"
```

INSERT é:

```
"INSERT INTO tabela (campo1,campo2,...) VALUES (valor1,valor2,...)"
```

SET é para UPDATE